# PHP drop down box not showing selected value

Tags: php

Hi I have a piece of php code which takes php variables from a database and then populates A drop down box.  This works fine but once the page updates it doesn't display the selected value and instead just displays the original list again.

I have played around with some different ideas of using isset to displays the selected value, but then it just displays that value and nothing else.

I have attached the original code where it works but always only shows the original list of values from the database.

If any body could provide a solution or even a nudge in the right direction then it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
if (isset($select) && $select != "location") {
    $select = $_POST['location'];
}
?>

<select name="location">
<?php
// Get records from database (table "name_list").
$list = mysql_query("select DISTINCT region_name from masterip_details WHERE country_code='GB' AND TRIM(IFNULL(region_name,'')) <> '' order by region_name asc");

// Show records by while loop.
while ($row_list = mysql_fetch_assoc($list)) {
    $location = $_POST['location']; ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_list['region_name']; ?>"
    <?php if  $row_list['region_name'] == $select) {
        echo "selected";
    } ?>><?php echo $row_list['region_name']; ?></option>        
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: where is $select set?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `&& $select !== "location"`?

Comment: @Alfo not compulsorily

Comment: $select is set in the 2nd line!

Comment: Check `$_POST['location']` has any of one dropdown box values.

Comment: Why would you set a variable AFTER you've checked that it exists?? This code will never run.

Comment: Ok, the $select variable doesn't hold any value. Which is probably the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sure you send that form with a post request?

Your code is unreadable
Better do something like this:

```
<?php

    //database request don't belong in the presentation layer
    $list=mysql_query("select DISTINCT region_name from masterip_details WHERE country_code='GB' AND TRIM(IFNULL(region_name,'')) <> '' order by region_name asc");
    $location = "";
    $isSelect = "";
    if(isset($_POST['location'])){
        $location = $_POST['location']; 
    }
    while($row_list=mysql_fetch_assoc($list)){
        if($row_list['region_name'] == $location ){ 
            $isSelect = "selected"; 
         } 
         echo '<option value="'.$row_list['region_name'].'" '.$isSelect.'  >'. $row_list['region_name'].'</option>';

    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the code much neater and easier to follow though it should an error around If(if($row ... But i will look at this and get it working as it is much neater than my way.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking the select value properly.

**Change this:**

```
if (isset($select) && $select != "location") {
    $select = $_POST['location'];
}
```

**TO**

```
if (isset($_POST['location']) && $_POST['location'] != "location") {
    $select = $_POST['location'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating the `<option>` tag, you may use the following:

```
<?php if ($row_list['region_name'] == $select) { echo "selected='true'"; } ?>
```

You may also like to check if the condition `$row_list['region_name'] == $select` is returning `true`. You may try to `echo` their result separately as:

```
echo ($row_list['region_name'] == $select)
```

or something similar that would show if you get `true` or not.

Comment: @Ranjith, yes it is not necessary to set it like this. The issue could be with `$row_list['region_name'] == $select` also. But adhering to XHTML conventions, every attribute should have a value.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But here its not the major problem. refer this  http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/option#Example_A link of w3.org

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the first line - actually the system will never execute 2nd line to assign `$select` because `$select` is never set:

```
if(isset($_POST['select']) && $select!="location") { $select=$_POST['location']; } ?>
```

Comment: and also the bit $location = $_POST['location'] in the while loop is not making sense...